# Naked Domain no Registro.br não redirecionando para www

Tags: google-app-engine, domínio, dns

Eu tenho um app hospedado no Google Appengine e estou usando um domínio próprio. Mesmo depois de editar a zona de DNS (faz uns 5 dias) ainda sim o naked domain não é redirecionado para o www.

Aqui estão as configurações no Registro.br.

```
Nome                      Tipo          Dados
example.com.br               A      216.239.32.21
example.com.br               A      216.239.34.21
example.com.br               A      216.239.36.21
example.com.br               A      216.239.38.21
www.example.com.br       CNAME      ghs.googlehosted.com
```

Aqui estão as configurações no Google Apps:

```
Primary Domain
Redirect the naked domain http://example.com.br to http://www.example.com.br
```

Answer (score 1):

Adicionei os seguintes valores de IPv6 e agora o redirect do naked domain funciona:

```
Nome                 Tipo     Dados
example.com.br       AAAA     2001:4860:4802:32:0:0:0:15
example.com.br       AAAA     2001:4860:4802:34:0:0:0:15
example.com.br       AAAA     2001:4860:4802:36:0:0:0:15
example.com.br       AAAA     2001:4860:4802:38:0:0:0:15
```

Não sei se é porque o registro BR demora muito tempo para atualizar os valores de DNS ou se os valores de IPv6 eram realmente necessários.

Os valores do IPv6 foram encontrados neste [artigo](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2579995?hl=en) do Google Apps Support.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar `@` (ou deixe em branco) a configuração do campo Nome (onde você está usando `example.com.br`) para todos os 4 registros `A` apontando para ips do Google . Além disso, se você ainda não o fez, habilite a configuração de *Naked Domain* no painel administrativo do Google Apps ([mais informações em inglês](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2518373)).

Pelo menos foi o que fiz para habilitar a funcionalidade usando meu domínio da [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/).

Comment: Eu já fiz isso e não funcionou.

Comment: Com @ ou deixando em branco? De acordo com [esse blog](http://www.gerenciandoblog.com.br/2011/01/como-migrar-seu-antigo-dns-para-o.html) para o registro.br deve ser deixado o registro em branco.

Comment: Espaço em branco. O sistema do Registro.BR não aceita o @.

Comment: Bom, apenas como desencarno, como encontrei várias referencias sobre o assunto ([mais uma](http://www.techtudo.com.br/dicas-e-tutoriais/noticia/2011/04/como-associar-um-dominio-br-recem-criado-ao-seu-blog-do-blogger.html)), você poderia seguir novamente exatamente esse procedimento com os quatro campos `A` em branco, o CNAME com `www` apontando para `ghs.googlehosted.com`, e o *naked domain* registrado no console do Google? Você tem algum problema contra passar seu domínio real também?

Comment: Outro ponto que eu esqueci de mencionar, obviamente meu aplicativo no App Engine têm uma configuração apontando para `www` ([mais informações em inglês](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain)), acredito que isso já esteja configurado corretamente para você.

Comment: Fiz tudo isso. Agora deu certo. Acho que foi porque eu fiz o redirect adicionando os valores AAAA de IPv6.

Comment: @Magritte dúvido muito (o meu domínio não está usando IPv6 e tudo funciona), mas que bom que resolveu :).

Answer (score 0):

O @ que aparece em configurações de DNS é adicionado automaticamente pelo editor de DNS do Registro.br, então basta deixar em branco que aquela entrada se refere a Naked Domain. 
O tempo de propagação de alterações no DNS próprio do Registro.br é de 24 horas.

Answer (score 0):

Usando um domínio personalizado

Quando você cria um aplicativo com o Google App Engine, o aplicativo é automaticamente servido no domínio `appspot.com` em `seu-app-ID.appspot.com`. No entanto, muitas vezes é desejável para servir o seu aplicativo em um domínio personalizado que você possui (`example.com`), em subdomínios específicos desse domínio (`app.example.com`), ou em qualquer ou todas as (`* .example.com`) subdomínios esse domínio. Segundo https://developers.google.com/

É fácil fazer isso com o App Engine. Primeiro, é claro, você deve adquirir um domínio através de um registro de domínio. Uma vez que você tiver um domínio, personalização de seu aplicativo para usar o seu domínio ou subdomínio envolve três etapas:

- Prove ao Google que você controla o domínio.
- Configure os servidores do Google para reconhecer o domínio.
- Atualizar os registros de DNS no registrador de domínios para apontar para os servidores do Google.

Todo o processo pode normalmente ser concluída em poucos minutos em seu computador.

Note-se que as instruções nesta página são para [aplicativos](http://www.ringtonesgratis.com.br/) App Engine que usam uma conexão HTTP normal e não são atendidos por meio do Google Apps. Aqui estão alguns procedimentos relacionados que necessitam de instruções diferentes:

- Para servir o seu aplicativo do Google App Engine por meio do Google Apps, ler sobre o App Engine no centro de ajuda do Google Apps.
- Para atribuir um domínio adicional a seus serviços do Google Apps, leia sobre os domínios personalizados no centro de ajuda do Google Apps.
- Para adicionar Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) (ou seja, um endereço HTTPS) para seu aplicativo do Google App Engine, você deve usar o serviço SSL fornecido com o Google Apps. Você vai encontrar informações e instruções em SSL para um domínio personalizado.